# Solve $(2x-5)y''+(4x-12)y'-4y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(2x-5)y''+(4x-12)y'-4y=0$

I have to find infinite series form solutions , $y=\sum a_nx^{n+r}$.

My solution:

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2n(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4na_nx^n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}12na_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4a_nx^n=0$

Re-index:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2(n+1)na_{n+1}x^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4na_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}12(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4a_nx^n=0$

The recursion equation is :

$a_{n+2}=\frac{(n+1)(n-6)a_{n+1}+4(n-1)a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}$

$a_2=-3a_1-2a_0$

$a_3=\frac{15a_1+10a_0}{3}$

$a_4=-6a_1-4a_0$

I cant get what the first solution is , and how to get the second solution , On the first solution is $a_0=0 , a_1=1$ and on the second one is $a_0=1,a_1=0$ ?

Help is welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282x-5%29y%27%27%2B%284x-12%29y%27-4y%3D0) says that $y(x) = Ae^{-2x} + Bx$. Since $a_4 = 2a_2$, hopefully $a_6 = 2a_4$ as well.

Comment: I can't understand "my solution": where is for example $\;-5y''\;$ in that development of series that you present? Apparently you forgot that $\;5\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ohh Thanks !

Comment: @TobyMak That should be $y=Ae^{-2x}+B(x-3)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, the constant also matters there.

Comment: Your formula $a_{n+2}$ is almost correct (add lost 5 multiplier to denominator). This formula can be used for $n\geq 1$. For $n=0$: $a_2=-\frac{6a_1+2a_0}{5}$. I don't understand your needs from question. Do you need to solve recurrence equation for $a_{n+2}$ ? Knowing answer you can try two cases: $a_0=1$, $a_1=-2$ and $a_0=-3$, $a_1=1$, which correspond to $e^{-2x}$ and $x-3$.